# How do I create a transparent table view in navigation controller with a background image in IOS 8?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, ios8, uitabbarcontroller

I am working on a Swift app in which I have a navigation view controller and in that I have a table view. The navigation view is in a tab controller view. So in this view, I have a top navigation bar, a table in the middle, and the bottom tab bar.

I'd like to create the view in such a way that the entire visible view should have a background image that is blurred (I know how to do that), and then the navigation bar, the tab bar, and the table itself should all have transparent backgrounds such that all the text and image content are all visible in the foreground against the blurred background image.

What is the best way to approach this? Thanks!

**Edit**

So my structure looks like:

Tabbed view
    -> Navigation controller view
        -> Table view

Comment: Do you want it completely invisible or are trying to change the alpha value?

Comment: Have a blurred background image for entire view, and then clearColor for all the other widgets, like your tableview and if there are any.

Comment: @soulshined Which component do you mean when you ask whether I want *it* completely invisible?

Comment: @Mrunal What do you mean clearColor? Like clear color their backgrounds?

Comment: @JohnDoe: Yes, I mean to say, your tableview is not have any type of background. It should display what is set in imageview which is behind it. And in that imageview add an image which is already semi-transparent.

Comment: The components your referencing. Transparent and translucent are two different things. I'm trying to clarify before I offer an answer. Do you want the backgrounds of your mentioned components transparent (completely invisible ?) or just translucent

Comment: @soulshined Oh I get it now. Yes, I want the components in the foreground to have completely transparent background. My current structure looks like: Tab bar view -> Navigation view -> Table view. So I need the background of the navigation bar, the tab bar, and the table to be completely transparent. But, I need to stick the blurred image in so it is in the background relative to all the above components I just mentioned.

Comment: @Mrunal So where do I put the image view relative to the tabbed view? I put in some information about what my current view hierarchy looks like.

Comment: @JohnDoe so basically you will have to create a UIView programmatically. Add the picture in the UIView you just created and then add the UIView to tableView. Then make your cell backgrounds clearColor and it's good to go

Comment: @soulshined So, that would make my navigation bar and the tab bar transparent as well?

Comment: @JohnDoe no. you have do that. either in storyboard or code by changing the attributes of the color to clearColor. Or you could simply set them to hidden for that specific view

Comment: @soulshined Okay, just tried adding an view to the table view, and that just pushed the table below the view I added – it isn't acting as the background

Comment: can you share how you added it please?